# What are best practices organizing css for the Asset Pipeline in Rails 4

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

What are best practices organizing css for the Asset Pipeline in Rails 4? I want to be able to share color variables among files, and want to control in what order the scss files are fired. Would it be better to not use the manifest syntax, rename the application.css to application.css.scss and use imports instead?

This is how I've structure the folder

```
assets/stylesheet:
--application.css
--colors.css.scss
--fonts.css.scss
--frameworks.css.scss
--layout.css.scss
--nav.css.scss
```

And the application.css file looks like this:

```
*= require_self
*= require frameworks
*= require fonts
*= require colors
*= require layout
*= require_tree .
```

And for example the fonts.css.scss looks like this:

```
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700,800,900);
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,900,700);
```

Comment: I've found this blog post, follows what the generators are doing, seems pretty legit: http://www.mattboldt.com/organizing-css-and-sass-rails/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use your custom variables, `@import` is the solution.

I don't use Assets Pipeline default `require` in SASS project. Instead I use `@import`.

```
//application.css.scss
@import "my_variables";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "others";
```

Comment: I found this to be the best solution myself. Wonder why this is not Rails default way of doing it?

Comment: @Andreas, I think the reason would be, not everybody use SASS and variables. Also import each file would be tedious.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SASS, you will find [this blog post](http://thesassway.com/beginner/how-to-structure-a-sass-project/) helpful from The Sass Way.

I have a example of [this structure on Github](https://github.com/abitdodgy/sass-project) too.

Something along the lines of this. You can make this more granular to fit your needs if your project is large.

```
+ modules
  - _base.scss
  - _mixins.scss
+ partials
  - _base.scss
  - _fonts.scss
+ vendor
  - bootstrap-custom.scss
- application.scss
```